# How to set environment variable permanently?

Tags: .net-core

i am using visual code on MAC. anytime I want to launch the project, I have to set the environment in the terminal before running the project.

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
dotnet watch run
```

How can I configure the environment once in the startup file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set that in code use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()` method

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");
```

And the `Main` method in your app is the good place to call it.

Comment: please can you provide more info about your answers. in which file and which method ?  am a bit new in cornet core

Comment: @Djama there is a `static void Main` method in the `Program.cs` file which is the entry poing for your app.

Comment: ok i have seen it, and set it there as you suggested before the host.Run(). it works !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I rather choose to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` on the OS. since it is used by the application.

If you set in the code, whenever you run your project (it doesn't matter if it is deployed or not) your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable will be always set.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open ~/.bash_profile
```

inside this file add

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

and close.

then whenever `dotnet watch run` command issued, the application will run in development mode.